# adding +1 to quarters (dates) in R

Tags: r

I have the below data and I want to add a `1` to each of the quarters (i.e. push the quarter ahead by 1 quarter)

I can do `d$quarter + 1` but this gives me quarter 4 as "quarter 5". How can I roll over quarter 4 to quarter 1 of the next year?

```
Data:


library(lubridate)

    dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2005/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)
    x_var <- rnorm(1000)

    d <- data.frame(dates, x_var) %>%
      mutate(quarter = quarter(dates),
             year = year(dates))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modulo 4 to have 4 as 0 without changing 1 to 3 then add 1:

```
d <- data.frame(dates, x_var) %>% mutate(quarter = (quarter(dates)%%4)+1, year = year(dates))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it on the dates column instead

```r
d$nextquarter <- d$dates + months(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d2 <- d %>%  mutate(new_date = dates %m+% months(3)) %>% 
  mutate(quarter2 = quarter(new_date),
         year2 = year(new_date))
```